# Sanitizing user supplied XSLT

Tags: xslt, xss, saxon

We have an application which uses XSLT to format XML data for display as XHTML.

The system is able to cope with arbitrary XML schemas, so Schemas and XSLTs need to be uploaded by users of the system. Clearly this is a task which is only allowed to Admin level users, however it's also a pretty large bulls-eye to aim at so I'm trying to make it more secure.

I should mention that we're using Saxon 9.0 B

Is there any standard way to sanitise user supplied XSLT? So far I have identified three possible issues although I am concious that there may be more which I simply haven't thought of:

1. xsl:import and document() functions can get at the server file system. This is pretty easy to lock down using a custom URI Resolver so I'm pretty confident I have this covered
2. output can contain javascript. I'm thinking of using something like OWASP Anti-Samy to white-list the allowed output tags.
3. XSLT can call java functions. This is the one which is currently causing me a headache. I don't want to turn the capability off altogether (although at the moment I can't even see how to do that) because we're using it. My preferred solution would be to be able to lock down the acceptable java namespaces so that only known safe functions can be executed. I am open to other suggestions though.

The gold standard would be a standard library which just handles all known XSLT based vulnrabilities, but failing that any suggestions on tackling the issues listed above (especially 3) would be much apprieciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Saxon has a configuration option to disable use of "reflexive" (dynamically loaded) extension functions. This doesn't prevent use of "integrated" extension functions which have been explicitly registered in the configuration via an API. This seems to meet your requirement of allowing the service provider to register extension functions, but not allowing the stylesheet author to do so.

You can be even more selective if you want by defining your own JavaExtensionFunctionFactory to control how extension function calls are bound. This is fairly low-level system programming and you'll probably need to study the source code to see which methods you need to override to meet your needs.

As well as document(), you need to consider collection(), unparsed-text(), xsl:result-document. In all cases there are Saxon hooks that allow you to control the behaviour.

Comment: thank you, this is all very useful and exactly the sort of information I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think uploading and executing anybody's XSLT on the server is something sensible to do**.

There are things that one can't prevent or detect, such as a Denial Of Service attack like:

1. Endless recursion that eats up all available memory and crashes the server with stack overflow.
2. Transformation that takes many minutes or hours -- as the halting problem is undecidable, we don't know if this is an intentional perpetual loop, or accidental programmer error, or a computation that may or maynot converge.

There are certainly many other exploits, such as referencing a recursively defined entity ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that it's probably impossible to make 100% secure, but at the moment it's a massive collection of horrible holes and I'm looking to see how many of them I can reasonably plug.

Comment: @JosephRogers, If you expect any kind of a malicious attempt, you can't ignore the types of DOS described in this answer -- and the fact that there is no defense against these types of DOS. The logical conclusion from this fact is *not* to allow foreign code execution on your servers. Understanding this early enough will save many hours of effort.